# Row numbering formula not working on crystal report layout

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report formula for row numbering that doesnt seem to work. Just repeats 001 on all rows.

```
NumberVar rowNum;
If OnFirstRecord or {Invoice Number Field} <> Previous({Invoice Number Field}) then
  rowNum := 0;
rowNum := rowNum + 1;
Right('000' + toText(rowNum, 0, ''), 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the clause

```
or {Invoice Number Field} <> Previous({Invoice Number Field})
```

That logic is needed only if you need to reset the counter when you reach a new invoice number.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's cause I'm trying to create a sequential row numbering for 2 details section.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Is the problem solved?
Note that if the formula is placed in Details a and not in Details b it will not be evaluated in Details b.

Comment: Hi Millet, I also want it to work for details b. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please explain the desired behavior.